# Does “a” change meaning of phrase?

Tags: meaning

I wrote two phrase below. Are the meanings of these same or different  because of “a”.

> He made a ten dollars short payment.
>
> He made ten dollars short payment.

Comment: Not sure about making any change...but it may make it ungrammatical.

Comment: Count nouns like "payment" generally require a determiner like "a", so only the first one is possible. I would treat "ten-dollars-short" as a compound adjective, hyphenated as shown.

Comment: @BillJ what confuse me is that is total payment $10 or the payment $10 short?

Comment: I interpret it as meaning that the payment was short by $10.

Answer (score 1):

It's an awkward way to phrase the sentence. I'd be inclined to say something more like:

> His payment was ten dollars short.

However, if you really wanted to preserve your original wording for some reason, then keep the indefinite article, and use hyphens to make a compound adjective:

> He made a ten-dollars-short payment.

As mentioned on [one grammar website](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp):

> Hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea. This is called a **compound adjective**.
>
> Examples:
>   *an off-campus apartment
>
>   state-of-the-art design*

Answer (score 0):

Neither version sounds correct at the moment. I would write/say it as:

> He made a payment that was ten dollars short.